# Fourier transform of an exponentially decaying waveform

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, signal-processing

Consider an atom oscillating at a certain frequency. The amplitude of the oscillation decreases over time such that the waveform can be modeled by an exponential function, but the frequency remains unchanged. The Fourier transform (FT) of this waveform reveals that it is composed of an infinite number of frequencies, since the FT of an exponential gives a Lorentzian curve.

My question is how does the Fourier transform make sense physically, considering the atom cannot simultaneously oscillate at an infinite number of frequencies and one frequency only. The time and frequency domains seem to be describing completely different situations despite the result being technically equal.

Comment: As in the atom is oscillating with a set frequency simple sinusoidal wave that's damped by an exponential? If the exponential has no frequency dependence in the exponent then it doesn't make a difference in the FT. If the oscillation is simple the Fourier series is a finite amount of sines/cosines.

Comment: Do you find it *more* believable that an atomic oscillation would have started in $t=-\infty$ and will end in $t=+\infty$ and all without the slightest amplitude or phase fluctuation?

Comment: @Tratticus. I might be misunderstanding your comment, but the Fourier transform of something like $e^{i\omega t}e^{-\gamma t}\Theta(t)$ is a function that is basically non-zero everywhere, i.e., there are an infinite number of Fourier components.

Comment: @hyportnex That's what the FT tells me, that the atom will oscillate at different frequencies for an infinite amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you consult chapter 10 of "Spectrophysics" by Anne P Thorne which describes spectral line shapes and broadening effects.  The exponential decay to which you refer is a classical approximation of what is actually a quantum effect.

To answer directly, the fact that the waveform is decaying exponentially (or changing amplitude in any way at all) tells you that there cannot be only one frequency present: a single frequency would be indicated by a constant amplitude sinusoid of infinite extent (by definition).  There is instead a spectrum of frequency components.  The "other" frequency components all combine mathematically (by amplitude and phase) in such a way as to "snuff out" the oscillation after a certain number of cycles as well as suppressing any signal before the start of the signal.  If the signal is short, with a sudden onset and a short duration, then more frequency components are required to suppress the oscillation away from the peak of the signal.

You can regard the actual waveform as being a product of a single frequency sinusoid and an "apodising function" which is a single-sided exponential in time.   The equivalent explanation in the frequency domain may be obtained by using the convolution theorem which states that the spectrum will look like that of the fundamental oscillation frequency convolved with the spectrum of the apodising function.

The spectrum of a sinusoid is a delta-function (or two, if you like double-sided spectral representations).  The spectrum of a single-sided exponential is complex (as the exponential is an asymmetric function), but it is related to a Lorentzian function (see Bracewell "The Fourier Transform and its Applications", p 418).  The end result is (approximately) a Lorentzian spectral profile (convolution with a delta-function being "simple").

The spectrum has a definite and possibly sharp peak at what you described as the "certain frequency", but it also has width indicating the presence of additional frequency components (of lower amplitude).  These are the components that describe the decay function in the time domain.

I suggest that there is no conflict here.  An atom CANNOT emit at a single frequency unless it spends an infinite time doing so. In reality, transitions occur over particular times (curtailed in the classical approximation by collisions with other atoms - so-called pressure broadening).  There is an expected "uncertainty" in the frequency (caused by the finite transition time which can be shown by those skilled in the art of quantum mechanics to be a manifestation of the uncertainty principle.

I hope that this helps somewhat (although my answer is late!).